# Mousemove fixed background not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, effects

I was just following [this tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Ns85ghz0oVs) the other day. Everything quite goes well with the basic layout, but it seems that the background isn’t staying fixed while on mousemove. Here’s the entire project I’m working on:

```js
let light = document.getElementById('light');

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  light.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  light.style.top  = e.pageY + 'px';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0 0 25 / 0.9), rgb(0 0 25 / 0.9)), url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="light"></div>
```

I don’t know, but I assume that Chrome has deprecated the feature already. Therefore the effect isn’t working properly anymore. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your JavaScript was invalid: it was using non-ASCII quotes, hence the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [not deprecated](https://caniuse.com/background-attachment), it just not work like this, the `fixed` value [as per specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment#values) means:

> `fixed`
>
> The background is fixed relative to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, the background doesn't move with
> the element. (This is not compatible with [`background-clip: text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#values).)

Thus, because your viewport (`<div id="light"></div>`) is moving, not scrolling, the background image is moving also.

But your intention is clear, that trick can be done without `background-attachment`:

```js
let light = document.getElementById('light');

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  light.style.transform = `translate3d(${e.pageX}px, ${e.pageY}px, 0)`;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#light {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Highlight Image</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="light"></div>
</body>

</html>
```